# Remove an item on the listview inside CustomArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Each item of my `listview` has a image button, if you click that I'd like to remove the item which the current image button is associated or currently focused.

```
listview = (QuickReturnListView) v.findViewById(R.id.carddemo_list_expand);

        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux",
            "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2",
            "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile" };


        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
          list.add(values[i]);
        }

        adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(getActivity(), list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

---

```
 public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
      private final Context context;
      private final ArrayList<String> values;

      public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.inner_base_header_cutom, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = list;
      }

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

v.remove = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
v.remove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


             //Global Variables 
            list.remove(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            //

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: And what's the problem ? Are you sure you could not found the answer to this question in existing answers ? There's plenty of questions on the subject.

Comment: parent is list or what ?

Comment: I Think that you should write `v.remove.setFocusable(true)` before you write `v.remove.setOnclickListener()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter` has the `remove(T object)` method that you should call to clean the dataset you provide to the superclass: inside onClick you should call

```
remove(list.get(position));
```

Comment: I got `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` sir.

Comment: that means that you are providing an array to the super class. Pass an ArrayList and you should be fine

Comment: It's working!. instead of passing `String[]`, I replaced it with `Arraylist<String>`

Answer (score 0):

To remove the item from list first the get position and the remove from list and call  notifyDataSetChanged() so list will be reloads.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

v.remove = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
v.remove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        parent.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        //

    }
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will write the list view OnItemclick listener in your Main activity..

And you will prefer 
ArrayList String> values = new ArrayList String>;

```
listStudies.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
                long i) {
            //You just remove your date from the String Array and give adapter notifychaged....
            values.remove(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```